# To Whom does report never sent?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/synopsis)

> They find a survey ship with a holographic recording made by its last surviving team member, a report never sent.

The above sentence didn't make any sense.

To Whom does report never sent?

Comment: By the way, the grammar in your question almost made me cry from hurting too much :( Did you mean *To whom was the report never sent?*

Comment: It doesn't matter. It wasn't sent anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does make sense. They found a report made by a surviving member, but this report was never sent. The sentence just omits [which was]:

> They find a Survey ship with a holographic recording made by its last surviving team member, a report [which was] never sent.

There are **many** cases where you don't specify to whom you're sending something because it's implicit or not important.

> -So, did you send the package yet?
> -No, I'll do it this afternoon.

In this case, it's not important because both speakers know what they're talking about.

In your case, on missions, reports are often sent to the higher-ups in the chain of command or to the people who didn't go on mission. Most likely, the writer didn't feel like mentioning to whom the report should have been sent, maybe to maintain an air of mystery.

Comment: "In your case, on missions, reports are often sent to the higher-ups in the chain of command or to the people who didn't go on mission." - Wonderful inference.

Comment: I'd take this to mean, the report was never sent to anyone. If someone said, "The report was never sent to Colonel Miller", then it might have been sent to someone else. Indeed the wording implies that it probably was. The list of people it was sent to just did not include Colonel Miller. But if he said, "The report was never sent", I'd take that to mean it wasn't sent to anybody.

Comment: @Jay: Mhh this is tricky, and while I partly agree with you, I don't think the wording implies that there were other people on the list. "The report was never sent to the Colonel" means that it was never sent to this person indeed, but it **could** have been sent to someone else, of which we have no knowledge. Then again, this case is quite dependant on interpretation.

Comment: @MadWard Yes, true. Depends on context. Like if all your reports are routinely sent to Col Miller and no one else, and someone asks, "Hey, was this report ever sent to Col Miller?", a "no" probably means it was not sent to anyone. But if copies of reports are normally sent to 20 people, and someone says, "Hey, Col Miller says he never got his copy", and someone replies, "You're right, it was never sent to Col Miller", odds are it was sent to at least some of the other 19. If it was never sent to any of them, I'd expect the reply to be, "No, it was never sent to anyone." Etc.

Comment: @MadWard sorry I didn't get your answer, I am asking to whom report never sent? .